# Azure IListBlobItem Oftype CloudBlob Linq Change List<CloudBlob>

Tags: linq, azure, azure-blob-storage, oftype

In my page ,I need to search containers and blobs by name,type and LastModified

```
 var selectedValue = ddlFileType.SelectedValue;
        AzureSettings container = AzureSettingsServices.Select(selectedValue.ParseInt(-1));
        if (ViewState[container.Name] == null)
        {
            IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> blobList = BlobHelper.GetFileListByContainer(container.Name);

            //I add the viewstate for not spending money in azure :)
            ViewState.Add(container.Name, blobList);

        }
         List<CloudBlob> list = null;
        string fileName = txtFileName.Text;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName))
        {
            //by name and date
            list = ((IEnumerable<IListBlobItem>)ViewState[container.Name]).OfType<CloudBlob>().Where(x => x.Name == fileName && x.Properties.LastModified >= dtDate.ValueRange.StartDate && x.Properties.LastModified <= dtDate.ValueRange.EndDate ).ToList();
        }
        else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName))
        {
            //by date
            list = ((IEnumerable<IListBlobItem>)ViewState[container.Name]).OfType<CloudBlob>().Where(x => x.Properties.LastModified >= dtDate.ValueRange.StartDate && x.Properties.LastModified <= dtDate.ValueRange.EndDate ).ToList();
        }
        if (list != null)
        {
          // by type
            list=list.OfType<CloudBlob>().Where(x => x.Name.Contains(selectedValue)).ToList();

            SelectedContainer = container.Name;
            grdFiles.DataSource = list;
            grdFiles.DataBind();
        }
```

The problem is I can not give  List < CloudBlob > list  as gridview datasource that is normal ,but how can I set to the List < CloudBlob > list in to **(** IEnumerable < IListBlobItem > bloblist or in my viewstate(note : in my viewstate is my Ilistblobitem list) **)** back for my gridview datasource

***UPDATE ERROR 2*** :

grdFiles.DataSource = ((IEnumerable)ViewState[container.Name]);

grdFiles.DataBind();

Here is the error about ,

> 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=7.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'  'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.CommonUtility+d__0`1[[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.IListBlobItem, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=7.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]'

```
> [SerializationException: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=7.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' Derlemesindeki 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.CommonUtility+<LazyEnumerable>d__0`1[[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.IListBlobItem, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=7.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]' ]
```

> System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(RuntimeType type) +12207601
>      System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(Type type, StreamingContext context) +230
>      System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo() +143
>
> System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder) +178
>      System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.Serialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder) +51
>      System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck) +540
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck) +131
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph) +17
>      System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.SerializeValue(SerializerBinaryWriter writer, Object value) +3046
>
> [ArgumentException: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.CommonUtility+d__0`1[[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.IListBlobItem, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=7.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]' türündeki 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.CommonUtility+<LazyEnumerable>d__0`1[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.IListBlobItem]' değerini seri hale getirme hatası.]
>      System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.SerializeValue(SerializerBinaryWriter writer, Object value) +3770
>      System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Serialize(Stream outputStream, Object stateGraph) +144
>      System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Serialize(Object stateGraph, Purpose purpose) +71
>      System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.System.Web.UI.IStateFormatter.Serialize(Object state) +39
>      System.Web.UI.Util.SerializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter formatter, Object stateGraph) +37
>      System.Web.UI.Control.EstimateStateSize(Object state) +45
>      System.Web.UI.Control.BuildProfileTree(String parentId, Boolean calcViewState) +71
>      System.Web.UI.Page.BuildPageProfileTree(Boolean enableViewState) +42
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5761

Comment: I find the error  , IEnumerable<IListBlobItem>  can not add to viewstate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you says IEnumerable can not add to viewstate and couldn't be a datasource to gridview.

As far as I know, IListBlobItem is an interface.The IEnumerable  contains three type of blob items.

```
CloudBlockBlob,CloudPageBlob,CloudBlobDirectory
```

So I suggest you could firstly check the type and convert to datatable or something else and then add it into ViewState.

Like below:

```
  DataTable d1 = new DataTable();
            d1.Columns.Add("Type");
            d1.Columns.Add("Id");
            d1.Columns.Add("Url");
            foreach (var item in blobs)
            {
                if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlockBlob))
                {
                    CloudBlockBlob blob = (CloudBlockBlob)item;

                    d1.Rows.Add("CloudBlockBlob", blob.Name, blob.Uri);
                }
                else if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudPageBlob))
                {
                    CloudPageBlob blob = (CloudPageBlob)item;
                    d1.Rows.Add("CloudPageBlob", blob.Name, blob.Uri);
                }
                else if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlobDirectory))
                {
                    CloudBlobDirectory blob = (CloudBlobDirectory)item;
                    d1.Rows.Add("directory", blob.StorageUri, blob.Uri);
                }

            }
            ViewState.Add(container.Name, d1);
```

Result:
[image]

---

> will viewstate better or shell I go azure for the list again in nonpostback and postback ?

As far as I know, you need pay for the list blob in azure( $0.10 LRS Cold per 10,000). So I suggest you could use viewstate to store the result of the listblob operation, if you don't need to update the list of blob.

---

> How can I handle sas expiration in my asp.net it will be more than 1000 user.. When I delete the blobContainer.GetPermissions(); and make a new one and set it.The another user who upload will fail because of I create a new sas for another user.

As far as I know, if you delete the blobContainer's permissions, it will delete the SAS access policy.

Then all SAS token which created according to this SAS access policy will useless.

Normally, we could create a access policy without expiry date.

Then you could specify the expiry date according to this access policy  when you're creating the signed URL for specific users.

The codes is like below:

```
  SharedAccessPolicy sharedAccessPolicy = new SharedAccessPolicy();
    sharedAccessPolicy.Permissions = SharedAccessPermissions.Read;
    sharedAccessPolicy.SharedAccessStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    //sharedAccessPolicy.SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1); No need to define expiry time here.

    BlobContainerPermissions blobContainerPermissions = new BlobContainerPermissions();
    blobContainerPermissions.SharedAccessPolicies.Add("default", sharedAccessPolicy);

    container.SetPermissions(blobContainerPermissions);

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue....");
    Console.ReadLine();
    CloudBlob blob = container.GetBlobReference(path);

    string sas = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessPolicy()
    {
        SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),//add expiry date only when you're creating the signed URL
    }
        , "default");

    Console.WriteLine(blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + sas);

    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + sas));

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue....");
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Besides, we could create 5 access policy, so I suggest you could create different access policy and create different SAS token for different user.

Comment: hmm.. yes you have right , new datatable is a good idea. Thank you for advice you are best :)  will viewstate better or shell I go azure for the list again in nonpostback and postback ?

Comment: Can I ask the second and the last question :) How can I handle sas expiration in my asp.net it will be more than 1000 user.. When I delete the blobContainer.GetPermissions(); and make a new one and set it.The  another user who upload will fail because of I create a new sas for another user.

Comment: Update the answer

Comment: then viewstate makes sense for me I need only listing.I think container read permission doesnt offer any security risk without blob reference:I present blob with Sas + uri.I'm sorry I tired you but I learned a lot, maybe other  friends can benefit from here ..

Comment: By using right SAS, we could read or update the blob with url + SAS. But if you leave your SAS token and it doesn't expire, then everyone could access this blob container without authorization. Besides, I'm glad to help others to solve the issue, if you feel the answer has alreay sloved your problem, please mark it as answer to help other people who faces the same issue. Thank you.

Comment: blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + sas from this uri can anyone go to my container ultimately I set read permission for my container ..  sharedAccessPolicy.Permissions = SharedAccessPermissions.Read;